# How do I use Guice Persist (Guice 3.0) with Wicket 1.5?

Tags: jpa, wicket, guice, guice-persist

I want to find out how to use Guice Persist (Guice 3.0) with Wicket 1.5.

I have not been able to find any 'hello world' type examples explaining how to do this, if you can link/provide such an example that would be great, and happily accepted as an answer.

In the meantime I'll be trying to create a 'hello world' type example myself, posting the code here as I progress. Help with making my code function properly will also be accepted as an answer.

---

I have set up a simple wicket project, very similar to the 'hello world' [guice example](http://wicketstuff.org/wicket/guice) from Wicket Examples, that uses guice for dependency injection. I now want to extend this project to also use JPA and Guice Persist, instead of "Hello World" I want to fetch a User from the database and display its username. I'm trying to achieve this using the instructions from the Guice wiki about [Guice persist](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/JPA).

UPDATE: So, I kinda got it working. In `WebApplication.init()` I injected a ServetModule like this `getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(new GuiceComponentInjector(this, new MyServletModule()));` and I also added GuiceFilter at the top of the web.xml file, before wickets filter.

Now when I run the application everything works, but I get this warning about using deprecated methods. Will look into this further.

> WARNING: You are attempting to use a deprecated API (specifically,
>   attempting to @Inject ServletContext inside an eagerly created
>   singleton. While we allow this for backwards compatibility, be warned
>   that this MAY have unexpected behavior if you have more than one
>   injector (with ServletModule) running in the same JVM. Please consult
>   the Guice documentation at
>   http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Servlets for more
>   information.

*Directory tree*

```
.
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── se
        │       └── lil
        │           ├── HomePage.html
        │           ├── HomePage.java
        │           ├── MyServletModule.java
        │           ├── WicketApplication.java
        │           ├── domain
        │           │   └── User.java
        │           └── service
        │               ├── IService.java
        │               └── JpaService.java
        ├── resources
        │   ├── META-INF
        │   │   └── persistence.xml
        │   └── log4j.properties
        └── webapp
            └── WEB-INF
                └── web.xml
```

*WicketApplication.java*

```
public class WicketApplication extends WebApplication {
    @Override
    protected void init() {
        super.init();
        getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(new GuiceComponentInjector(this,
                new MyServletModule()));
    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Page> getHomePage() {
        return se.lil.HomePage.class;
    }
}
```

*HomePage.java*

```
public class HomePage extends WebPage {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -918138816287955837L;

    @Inject
    private IService service;

    private IModel<User> model = new LoadableDetachableModel<User>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1913317225318224531L;

        @Override
        protected User load() {
            return service.getUser();
        }
    };

    public HomePage() {
        setDefaultModel(new CompoundPropertyModel<User>(model));
        add(new Label("name"));
    }
}
```

*HomePage.html*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<head>
<title>Wicket Examples - guice</title>
</head>
<body>
    <hr />
        Value: <b wicket:id="name">name goes here</b> <br />
    <hr />
</body>
</html>
```

*MyServletModule.java*

```
public class MyServletModule extends ServletModule {
    protected void configureServlets() {
        install(new JpaPersistModule("manager1"));
        filter("/*").through(PersistFilter.class);
    }
}
```

*IService.java*

```
@ImplementedBy(JpaService.class)
public interface IService {
    public User getUser();
}
```

*JpaService.java*

```
public class JpaService implements IService {
    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public User getUser() {
        Query q = em.createQuery("FROM User");
        q.setMaxResults(1);
        User u = (User) q.getSingleResult();
        return u;
    }
}
```

*User.java*

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "users")
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   
}
```

*web.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>wicketwithguice</display-name>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>wicket.wicketwithguice</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>applicationClassName</param-name>
            <param-value>se.lil.WicketApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>wicket.wicketwithguice</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

*persistence.xml*

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="manager1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>se.lil.domain.User</class> 
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="test"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="1234"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

*pom.xml*

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>se.lil</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicketwithquice</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <!-- TODO project name -->
    <name>quickstart</name>
    <description></description>
    <!-- TODO <organization> <name>company name</name> <url>company url</url> </organization> -->

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <hibernate-core.version>3.6.4.Final</hibernate-core.version>
        <mysql-connector-java.version>5.1.16</mysql-connector-java.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.6.1</log4j.version>
        <guice.version>3.0</guice.version>
        <wicket.version>1.5.2</wicket.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--GUICE DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>${guice.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${guice.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-persist</artifactId>
            <version>${guice.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- HIBERNATE DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MYSQL DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql-connector-java.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- WICKET DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
            <version>${wicket.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket-guice</artifactId>
            <version>${wicket.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- LOGGING DEPENDENCIES - LOG4J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <optimize>true</optimize>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Apache Nexus</id>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Just looking at this without really reading it, I'd have to say that it's likely way too localized. Can you generalize your problem into something other people might also run into?

Comment: @dlamblin I can see where you'r coming from, considering the amount of code I posted. What I'm looking for is a simple 'hello world' type example using wicket and guice persist. The code I posted reflects how far I've gotten creating such an example myself.

Comment: I would accept a link to a 'hello world' example as an answer. Help correcting my code would also be gladly accepted, right now the only issue is that it uses an deprecated API. If I get my code working properly by myself I'll just answer my own question :)

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look on this post and the comments:

http://blog.yanivkessler.com/2010/05/wicket-and-guice-alternate-route.html

Answer (score 1):

Wicket 1.5.3 and Guice 3 work. For wicket wicket-ioc, wicket-util and wicket-dev-utils were used besides  wicket core and wicket-guice.Jars were downloaded and created as a library in Netbeans7.0 and added to the web project.

Answer (score 0):

As the same message is learnt to be appearing when guice is integrated with shiro, the following mailing-list may be useful
"http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/shiro-user/201108.mbox/%3C4E454692.8090806@peachjean.com%3E"

Answer (score 0):

When Injector is obtained from ServletContext and added to GuiceComponentInjector no such message appears.The code for AppListener and others furnished here:

```
package cookbook;

import com.google.inject.persist.jpa.*;
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Injector;
import com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceServletContextListener;
import com.google.inject.servlet.ServletModule;
import com.google.inject.persist.PersistFilter;
public class AppListener extends GuiceServletContextListener{
    @Override
    public Injector getInjector() {
    return Guice.createInjector(
      new  JpaPersistModule("WickGui3PU"  ),
      new ServletModule() {
        @Override
        protected void configureServlets() {



          filter("/*").through(PersistFilter.class);


          bind(BookDAO.class).to (BookDAOImpl.class);
        }
    });
    } 
}
```

Add  in web.xml

```
<listener>
      <listener-class>cookbook.AppListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

The init() in WicketApplication should be as under:

```
 protected void init() {
        super.init();

                Injector injector = (Injector)getServletContext().getAttribute(Injector.class.getName());

        getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(new GuiceComponentInjector(this,injector));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will try this out in a few days.